# c++ data structure for storing millions of int16

Tags: c++, data-structures

Good afternoon.
I have the following situation: there are three sets of data, each set is a two-dimensional table in which about 50 million fields. (~ 6000 lines and ~ 8000 columns). 
That data are stored in binary files
Language - c + +

I only need to display this data.
But I stuck when tried to read.(std::vector used but the waiting time is too long) 
What is the best way to read\store such amount of data? (std::vectors, simple pointers, special libraries)?

Maybe links to articles, books, or just personal experience?

Comment: fread the binary block in one call?

Comment: You can memory-map the file, then use it as an array of arrays directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you shouldn't use plain old read and write on ifstream/ofstream. The following code doesn't take very long for a BigArray b( 6000, 8000 );

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

class BigArray {
public:
  BigArray( int r, int c ) : rows(r), cols(c){
    data = (int*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    if( NULL == data ){
      std::cout << "ERROR\n";
    }
  }
  virtual ~BigArray(){ free( data ); }

  void fill( int n ){
    int v = 0;
    int * intptr = data;
    for( int irow = 0; irow < rows; irow++ ){
      for( int icol = 0; icol < cols; icol++ ){
        *intptr++ = v++;
        v %= n;
      }
    }
  }

  void readFromFile( std::string path ){
    std::ifstream inf( path.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary );
    inf.read( (char*)data, rows*cols*sizeof(*data) );
    inf.close();
  }

  void writeToFile( std::string path ){
    std::ofstream outf( path.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary );
    outf.write( (char*)data, rows*cols*sizeof(*data) );
    outf.close();
  }

private:
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int* data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't need all this data at once, you may use a memory mapped file technique and read data as it was a giant array. Generally operating system / file system cache works well enough for most applications, but certainly YMMV.